# How to call a procedure that uses const and *?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, mikroc

I'm trying to implement a function about drawing a circle

```
void drawCircle(const circleType * circle)
```

Above is displayed how it's defined in the header file. I'm trying to use it in a program:

```
drawCircle(circle);
```

The circle is a struct (circleType) of 3 variables, each and every one defined before calling the procedure. Am I doing something obviously wrong? The error I'm getting is:

```
320 Cannot assign 'circle' to 'circle'
307 Illegal typecast 'can not convert to pointer' ''
```

IDE is mikroC PRO for AVR (v4.60.0.0). I aren't sure of the compiler included. Should also mention that I only get the error when optimization is set to 0 (otherwise, I simply get 'finished with errors' without any error message)

Answer (score 2):

```
void drawCircle(const circleType * circle)
```

expects a pointer to, the address of a `circleType` typed variable.

So assuming

```
typedef struct 
{  
  int xc; 
  int yc; 
  int rc; 
} circleType;

...

circleType circle = {...};
```

You want to call the function like this

```
drawCircle(&circle);
```

using the address-of operator `&` to gain `circle`'s address.

Comment: xc and yc are directly assigned values, while rc is calculated before assigned. Calling `drawCircle(&circle)` returns `Illegal pointer conversion` error message

Comment: @Nognir616: If this does not solve your issue(s?), you won't get around to provide more info, typically an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).